# Why does my player go behind the tile? Phaser.js

Tags: javascript, layer, phaser-framework

I can't understand why my character goes behind the tile.

[image: yolo]

Below is the suspected code

```
map1 = Game.add.tilemap('map1')
    map1.addTilesetImage('da','tileset')
    map1.setCollisionByExclusion([])
    ground = map1.createLayer(0)
    layer1 = map1.createLayer(1)
```

Full code here - https://pastebin.com/G71tjafA

Comment: Probably because you are drawing the player before the tileset

Comment: Thank you very much! You fixed my problem!